# M requires a parameter Validation Error

Tags: parameters, azure-data-factory

I have a bunch of Copy Pipelines in Azure Data Factory (v2).

They've been working fine up until today. Now whenever I try to publish changes, I am getting the following validation error: M requires a parameter

And of course with a validation error I can't save my changes.

Any dieas as to what I might look for? I have no idea where "M" is or what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had deleted parameters from the main pipeline and it would not let me add them back and save the pipeline. I ended up junking the pipeline and re-creating. It needed editing anyway. This fixed all of the validation issues.

Comment: we are also getting same error today. How did you identify which pipeline is throwing this error?

Comment: I had just recently made the change when the error started coming and I put 2 and 2 together. A quick look through the parameters for pipelines allowed me to identify.

Comment: I just hit this aswell. My pipelines have parameters, though no default values. Are default values required? We deploy through the Datafactory Management Client API, so i might be missing some required vals (the API is pretty barebones when it comes to validation)